# Replace two characters in tuple element with dictionary value

Tags: list, dictionary, tuples, more-itertools

I have a list of tuples (lot):

```
lot = [('490001', 'A-ARM1'),
       ('490001', 'A-ARM2'),
       ('490002', 'B-ARM3')]
```

Subsequently, I loop through every second tuple element and wish to replace every 'A-' and 'B-' characters by a dictionary value:

```
from more_itertools import grouper

dict = {'A-': 'ZZ', 'B-': 'XX'}

for el1, el2 in lot:
   for i, j in grouper(el2, 2):
       if i+j in dict:
           lot2 = [ (el2.replace( (i+j), dict[i+j] )) for el1, el2 in lot ]
print(lot2)
```

After 'lot2 = ' something is going wrong, my output is
`['A-ARM1', 'A-ARM2', 'XXARM3']` instead of `[ZZARM1', 'ZZARM2', 'XXARM3']`

Can anyone give me a hint on how to resolve this? Also, if you think I can write this more elegantly, feel free to let me know. I'm eager to learn. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the shortest solution, but it should work:

```py
lot2 = []
for el1, el2 in lot:
    lookup = el2[:2]
    if lookup in dict:
        lot2.append(dict[lookup] + el2[2:])
    else:
        lot2.append(el2)
```